# Div with special curved side

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create the bottom curved side of this image with css. Is it possible and how to do it ?
[image]

Comment: `border-radius: 0 0 45% 45%;`

Comment: This doesn't work. The image corners looks like a square. Only the side bottom side is rounded.

Comment: You could try a permutation of `border-bottom-left-radius: 50% 20%;`. That's as far as CSS can go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this way:

```css
body {padding: 15px;}
.border img {
  border-top-left-radius:     5px;
  border-top-right-radius:    5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100px 25px;
  border-bottom-left-radius:  100px 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #666;
}
```

```html
<div class="border">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250" alt="" />
</div>
```

#### Preview:

[image]